# To which HTML element's event is an asp:RegularExpressionValidator client side validation bound?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, webforms

This is a very specific question about how the client side (javascript) validation of a ASP.NET WebForms asp:RegularExpressionValidator works. *Note: It is not about the actual regular expression!*

**My goal is to register an event on the client side that gets handeled BEFORE the regex validation.**

Consider the following code (simplified, from the .aspx page)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMultiId" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
ID="RegularExpressionValidatorMultiId" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
ControlToValidate="TextBoxMultiId" ErrorMessage="Oops!"
SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="assigned_in_code">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Then, I also load this jQuery snippet (in addons.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form input[type='text'], form textarea").on("change", function () {
        $(this).val(function (i, value) {
            alert('trim addon this:=' + this.id + ' trimmed:=' + value.trim());
            return value.trim();
        });
    });
});
```

I would expect that, on any change of the text input's value, the `onchange` event would fire, causing the handler to alert and trim the value of the input. Then the validator should validate the trimmed input only.

However, this is what actually happens:

1. I make change to the input (by pasting a text with the keyboard and naviating away)
2. I get alerted immediately as expected
3. I press OK to dismiss the alert
4. The input's value gets trimmed and shows as such
5. The regular expression complains about a mismatch by showing it's red text "Oops!"

However, the moment after I dismiss the box, the value of the input should get trimmed, causing the validator to validate the trimmed text, which satisfies the regex.

**It seems that the validator validates the pasted text, not the trimmed text. Why? How to trim so, that the trimmed variant gets validated?**

*Note: I am aware of https://forums.asp.net/t/1749522.aspx?Capturing+RegularExpressionValidator+event+client+side but I do not want to change existing code, plus, this actually should work on all validators in my code not just regex ones at a later time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not what event ASP.NET is using but the execution order. The ASP.NET validator is being attached to the `change` event before your code, that's why it's being executed first.

One possible solution is forcing the validation again from your javascript event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form input[type='text'], form textarea").on("change", function (event) {
        $(this).val(function (i, value) {
            alert('trim addon this:=' + this.id + ' trimmed:=' + value.trim());
            return value.trim();
        });
        ValidatorOnChange(event);
    });
});
```

Another possible solution, which I don't like much because it looks quite brittle, is moving your code **above** the form so you can be sure that it will be first in line in the execution list.

```
<script src="jquery">
<script>
//your code
</script>
<form>
...
```

Comment: Actually I currently moved the code to the END of the form (so that my controls are available), this way it works. I do not use "document ready" anymore.

Comment: Your first solution works fine for my simplified version, however the actual page has multiple validations and handling the change twice breaks things up. I will go with the second solution, but with the adaptations mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: @kblock and others: I provide my current implementation (simplified) in it's own answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

**For future reference, I post my (simplified) implemented solution.** It is based on the second proposal by kblok in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308283/79485).

To register an event before the .NET WebForms validators do, I execute that code right at the botton of the page, as last item inside the `form` element (using a master page and the script in it's own js file):

Here's my code (in Public.Master):

```
        ...
        <!-- container-main end -->

        <%--Javascript used for master and content--%>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.min.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/application-addons.js") %>'></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my code (in application-addons.js):

```
// Trim all input fields. This helps with copy-pasted text accidentally having surrounding spaces.
// This intentionally does not affect inputs for passwords.
// Hint about execution time: The following code is intentionally not executed at document ready, but as soon as loaded.
// Doing so allows to register these input event handlers here BEFORE the regular ASP.NET validator controls 
// register their handlers. This way, the trimming gets applied before the validation.
// However, this implementation relies on the fact that all page cotrols, plus jQuery are already available at this stage.
$("form input[type='text'], form textarea").on("change", function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, value) {
        return value.trim();
    });
});
```

ASP.NET now will add it's client side validation event handler code AFTER my event handlers have been added. **Now, when the text in an input field changes, the text gets trimmed first, then validated.**

Addon: This is how it looks in the rendered page (using Google Chromes Developer Tools:

[image: ValidationScripts added by the ASP.NET Engine]